# how to use ParseLiveQuery in a pm2 cluster?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, websocket, pm2

We use parse-server for our backend. To scale it to the cpu count of the hosts we use pm2 cluster. Now we want to switch the communication with the client to ParseLiveQueries, but the pm2 clustering and the websocket connection that sticks to one particular process are not working well together. Messages that are created in another process not beeing sent to the client.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

ok. got it working.

First, install `redis` and start `redis-server`. Second, update your config to provide

```
"liveQuery": {
  "classNames":["Your", "Objects"],
  "redisURL": "redis://<redis-host>:6379"
},  
"liveQueryServerOptions":{
  "redisURL": "redis://<redis-host>:6379"
},  
"startLiveQueryServer": true
```

then all changes are published via the redis-server to the livequery-servers so that every livequery server is triggered by every change.